# Does PHPWord support .dot extension?

Tags: php, phpword

I'm importing a file with .dot extension but I get a error:

```
ZipArchive::locateName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object
```

The weird thing is that a .dotx file does work. Is .dot not supported anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [its `README.md`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/README.md):

> The current version of PHPWord supports Microsoft [Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) (OOXML or OpenXML), OASIS [Open Document Format for Office Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) (OpenDocument or ODF), [Rich Text Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) (RTF), HTML, and PDF.

Office Open XML is the newer Microsoft Office file format consisting of a zip archive containing several other files. [`.dotx` files are Office Open XML files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Office_filename_extensions).

In contrast, `.dot` files are not zip archives. They're for legacy versions of Microsoft Office.

Office Open XML is an open specification, making it much easier to use than legacy Office formats by third-party applications. This is probably one of the reasons that PHPWord supports it but doesn't support legacy file types.

I suggest saving your `.dot` file as a `.dotx` file in a modern version of Word and then working with the `.dotx` version of the file in your PHP code.